# Polymer 1.0 - Change Property Value Not Updated in Dom Repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I have a `dom-repeat` element, and when this is rendered it only has a `name` property filled out, and the `price` will be populated by an ajax reponse:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="myId" items="{{arr}}">
       <div>[[item.name]]</div>
       <div>[[item.price]]</div>
</template>
```

The problem is that the `price` isn't rendered after the response is gathered.

I tried:

```
document.querySelector('#myId').render();
```

After the response has been received, but doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

I can do `this.set('arr.x.price', value)` where `x` is the index of my object in the array, but my context is inside a function that does not know the index unless I calculate it, which isn't hard, but surely there must be a better way?

Comment: You have to update the array with this.set / this.push

Comment: @Alon The object whose property I update is given inside a function that does not know its index inside the array. How would you write that? Do I have to search its index for me to do `this.set('array.x.price', value)`?

Comment: I think `this.fire('arr-changed')` should work, but the better way would probably be to postpone rendering the element until all data is available.

Answer (score 3):

Array update approaches

1. either use `this.set` to update the array values. Ref: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding
2. or After updating all the array values you can do `this.notifyPath('arr',this.arr)`. Ref: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path

If you use approach 1. Then you can have observe property to listen for changes to a sub fields. Ref: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#filtering-and-sorting-lists

```
<template is="dom-repeat" id="myId" items="{{arr}}" observe="price">
```

If you use approach 2, then the `dom-repeat` should refresh automatically after array update.

If it still does not work, then use the `render()` method to force render of content. Ref: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/api/#dom-repeat:method-render

```
this.$.myId.render()
```

Comment: Thanks for the sum up of the various ways. I'm still looking for a way to update a specific property with Polymer knowing without having to go through the entire chain. Not sure if any way exists yet or not though.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the updated array to be rendered, you can update it and then `set` the value via a clone. For example:

```
this.arr[0].price = 99;
let arr_clone = this.arr.slice(0);
this.set('arr', arr_clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you update the array with this.push('myarray', {item}); then that will trigger Polymer's binding observers.